# Hiding a button inside a div from code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a aspx page and i want to hide the button from cs file based on my some condition

My .aspx looks like :

```
<asp: Content Id="contentid" >
<% if (!IsRedeemCardFlowOptin)
       { %>
       <ul id="ulid" class="abc">      
       </ul>
        <div class="bcd" id ="div1">
               <div id="div2"></div>
               <div id="div3"></div>
           <div id="div4" runat="server">
                     <h4><%= m_AutoRenewInfo.NewPageContent.ArCsidOffHeader%></h4>
                     <button class="abc bcd cde" title="Button" id="buttondiv"><span>Button</span></button>  //Want to hide this button
               </div>
           </div>
 <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Now in the cs file i want to hide the button with id "buttondiv", how can i do that

In my cs file, i try this 2 things but it doesnt work

```
Control myDiv = (Control)FindControl("buttondiv");
myDiv.Visible = false;
```

Or

```
foreach (Control c in contentid.Controls)
{
    if (c.ID == "buttondiv")
       {
           c.Visible = false;
       }
}
```

Can anyone let me know

Comment: Just give that button a CSS class that contains: `display:none`.

Comment: I want that on cs file based on some condition

Comment: So, just add the class conditionally in the .cs code.

Comment: Thats what i want, see my cs file, things that i try, findcontrol and loop, but it does not work.

Comment: No. In your `if` condition, just manually add a class name (that contains `display:none` and is already written into your .html file) to the element.

Comment: @remitly1: It "doesn't work" because you're trying to access something that isn't a control as though it were.  Make it a control, then you can use it as a control.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be used as a server-side control, the button would need to *be* a server-side control.  Add `runat="server"`:

```
<button class="abc bcd cde" title="Button" id="buttondiv" runat="server">
```

Then (unless you've broken the designer somehow, it's been a while since I've used Web Forms) you should have an `HtmlControl` object in your class that you can set without the need to "find" the control:

```
this.buttondiv.Visible = false;
```

Comment: I kept the `runat="server"` on the above div, because i dont want the page to refresh and i have some javascript associated on that button so cant keep `runat="server"` on button.

Comment: @remitly1: Why can't you make the button a server-side control?  That's exactly what you're trying to do in your code-behind.  If doing so causes some other problem with other unrelated code, address that problem as well.  Though I suppose you have other options, such as surrounding the button in a server-side conditional statement to emit or not emit the button based on some class-level condition.  That's not really "the web forms" way of doing this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly keep this in css file.

```
#buttondiv{
display:none;
}
```

Or apply style inline like below:

```
<button class="abc bcd cde" title="Button" id="buttondiv" style="display:none"><span>Button</span></button>
```

Comment: This has a very different effect than setting the `.Visible` property in the code-behind.  In the case of CSS, the HTML content is still sent to the client.  When setting it from server-side, it isn't.

Comment: He means to hide that based on a condition he has server side, not just hide always the element

Comment: ohh ok got that